# linux machine taking a long time to resolve network addresses

Tags: networking, dns

I have a linux mint laptop I have with a direct cable connection to my home network. When I hit fast.com or speedtest.net, I generally get about 40-60MB/s, which is fine.

However, any connection to the outside world seems to take quite a while-- like after typing in fast.com and hitting enter, the browser seems to hang for up to 5-6 seconds before beginning to load the page.

My DNS servers are the public Google servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) though the network interface seems to add my local router (192.168.1.1) as a DNS server as well, even though it's not set in the network settings-- I'm not sure how or why.

Any ideas what could be causing this lag?

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself - you have the local router as a DNS server when it isn't one - so what is happening is that computer is attempting to query the local one first, then it times out, then the other servers are attempted and work.

The most likely reason this is showing up would be if your computer is getting its IP addresses via DHCP from the router - the router is also specifying the DNS servers.  Modify the router to provide the correct DNS servers.